# Need help on getting data from API with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I recently learn about getting data from REST API using axios, but I encounter a problem. So I want to fetch some data from an API, here is my code:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Popup, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet'
import '../Map.css'

const GradientMap = () => {
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(()=>{
    getData();
 })
 const getData = async ()=>{
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/in-data')
    setData(response.data)
 }

 const getColor = (name)=>{...
 }

 return (
    <div>
        <GeoJSON data={CIKARANG_UTARA} style={{color: getColor(CIKARANG_UTARA.features[0].properties.Name)}}>
            <Popup>
                {CIKARANG_UTARA.features[0].properties.Name} <br/> Total Weight: {data[0].Total_Weight}
            </Popup>
        </GeoJSON>
        <GeoJSON data={CIKARANG_BARAT} style={{color: getColor(CIKARANG_BARAT.features[0].properties.Name)}}>
            <Popup>
                {CIKARANG_BARAT.features[0].properties.Name} <br/> Total Weight: {data[1].Total_Weight}
            </Popup>
        </GeoJSON>
        <GeoJSON data={CIKARANG_TIMUR} style={{color: getColor(CIKARANG_TIMUR.features[0].properties.Name)}}>
            <Popup>
                {CIKARANG_TIMUR.features[0].properties.Name} <br/> Total Weight: {data[2].Total_Weight}
            </Popup>
        </GeoJSON>
        <GeoJSON data={SUKATANI} style={{color: getColor(SUKATANI.features[0].properties.Name)}}>
            <Popup>
                {SUKATANI.features[0].properties.Name} <br/> Total Weight: {data[3].Total_Weight}
            </Popup>
        </GeoJSON>
        <GeoJSON data={CIBITUNG} style={{color: getColor(CIBITUNG.features[0].properties.Name)}}>
            <Popup>
                {CIBITUNG.features[0].properties.Name} <br/> Total Weight: {data[4].Total_Weight}
            </Popup>
        </GeoJSON>
    </div>
 )
}

export default GradientMap
```

The error is in the data[0].Total_Weight, it works when I save the file, but after I reload my browser it becomes an error, I tried to do console.log(data) and it returns an empty array. The API works fine, here is the response:

```
[
 {
  "Area": "CIKARANG UTARA",
  "Total_Weight": 283,
  "Total_OR_Weight": 135,
  "Total_IN_Weight": 148
 },
 {
  "Area": "CIKARANG BARAT",
  "Total_Weight": 0,
  "Total_OR_Weight": 0,
  "Total_IN_Weight": 0
 },
]
```

Here is the condition before reloading the browser (you can see, there is no error and the total weight fetched successfully):
[image: before]

And here is the condition after reloading my browser:
[image: after]

I don't know what to do, I am new to react and axios, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an empty array:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

Then trying to read the first value from that empty array:

```
Total Weight: {data[0].Total_Weight}
```

Since the array is empty, the first element of that array is `undefined`.

What you can do is conditionally not render the elements until the array has values.  For example:

```
return (
  data.length > 0 ?
  <div>
    ... the rest of your HTML
  </div> :
  <div>Loading...</div>
);
```

You can replace that "loading" element with whatever you want to show on the page while the API data is being fetched.  But you can't *use* the API result until after it's fetched, at which point updating the state will trigger the component to re-render with the data.

Comment: It works, Thanks a lot